# Hibernate, Associations not working

Tags: hibernate, associations, one-to-many

I have a model like this

**Seizurs => MatCountry => MatCountryI18n**

When I try to query the data like so

```
criteria.
createAlias("matCountry","seizure_country",CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN).       
createAlias("seizure_country.matCountryI18ns","seizure_country_translation",CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN).
add(Restrictions.eq("seizure_country_translation.matLanguageCode", "de").
setFetchMode("seizure_country", FetchMode.JOIN).
setFetchMode("seizure_country_translation", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

and get the data from the DB

```
List<Seizure> seizures = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

I would expect that hibernate gives me only those objects (specifically those child objects) that match my given query (where translation.matLanguageCode = de)

But when I access the child objects for **MatCountryI18n**

```
logger.info("Seizures: "+seizures.get(0).getMatCountry().getMatCountryI18ns().size());
```

It gives me back *ALL* the MatCountryI18n objects that are associated with
**MatCountry**

Please help.

What am I'm doing wrong.

Regards JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking hibernate to give you all Seizurs that have MatCountry's that have one or more MatCountryI18n's with matLanguageCode == 'de'. Which is exactly what you are getting.

It sounds like you want to only select only the specific MatCountryI18n's with matLanguageCode == 'de'. I would do this by staring your select with a MatCountryI18n's Criteria and fetching the Seizurs though your associations in reverse order as you are doing right now. Either programatically or though a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/index.html?org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html).

Comment: My usecase is that I whant to have a list of all Seizures, their Country and the appropriate translation for that country (i.e. in English)

Comment: I understand, but what you are doing is selecting Seizurs with some join's and where statements on those joins. Hibernate will return Seizurs and use your normal mapped associations when you access MatCountry. That is why I suggested to select  MatCountryI18n and through the reverse association build your List< Seizurs > to return from that. Or, use a custom ResultTransformer.

Comment: Thanks I will go with the ResultTransformer as depicted in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations

Comment: Cool! It didn't even have to be a custom build one. Thanks, I learned something new here too :)